# Scrollview с кастомным ползунком

Tags: android, scrollview

Есть Scrollview с bitmap в качестве ползунка. Проблема заключается в том, что ползунок ходит исключительно по части слайдера(либо посередине, либо только сверху или снизу, см. рис.). На изображении прокручено в самый низ (а ползунок не внизу). Возможно ли это исправить и как?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Дайте угадаю - текста где-то 1.25 страницы и бегунок останавливается ровно на 25% отметке, там, где по идее должен быть отрисован "длинный" бегунок?

Comment: Именно так. А нужен кругленький, как в дизайне